# Theos/Logos Debug Logging

Tags: objective-c, socat

I use theos a lot in creating jailbreak tweaks and to debug I have been using the built-in `%log`, and following all messages through the mac terminal by SSHing into the iphone and `watch`ing the output by using socat - `UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/lockdown/syslog.sock >watch`.

Now, when using this type of logging, you get every single update made to the syslog itself, which is a lot of information that I usually don't need(want) to see. I really just want to see what pertains to what I am logging.

**My question: is there a way to debug my tweak connecting through socat to a custom log? Where only my updates are being logged?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use "socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/lockdown/syslog.sock | grep YourApp" for parsing